# Opencart - Additonal images on Wishlist

Tags: variables, opencart

Trying to get Additional Product images visible on other pages, like the Wishlist for example (but I'm actually using it on a Wholesale mod that's similar). I'm really trying to learn how this part of OpenCart works, but I can't seem to grasp it.

I've added this to the "Wholesale.php" controller (from the "Product.php" controller):

```
$results = $this->model_catalog_product->getProductImages($this->request->get['product_id']);

foreach ($results as $product_info) {
 $this->data['image'][] = array(
  'popup' => $this->model_tool_image->resize($result['image'], $this->config->get('config_image_popup_width'), $this->config->get('config_image_popup_height')),
  'image' => $this->model_tool_image->resize($result['image'], $this->config->get('config_image_additional_width'), $this->config->get('config_image_additional_height'))
 );
}
```

Then I add this ('image2') to the array right below it:

```
    $this->data['products'][$product_info['product_id']] = array(
      'num' =>  $start + $count,
      'image' => $product_info['image'] ? $this->model_tool_image->resize($product_info['image'], $pricelist['image_width'], $pricelist['image_height']) : $this->model_tool_image->resize('no_image.jpg', $this->config->get('config_image_product_width'), $this->config->get('config_image_product_height')),                        
THIS ONE >>> 'image2' => $product_info['image'] ? $this->model_tool_image->resize($product_info['image'], $pricelist['image_width'], $pricelist['image_height']) : $this->model_tool_image->resize('no_image.jpg', $this->config->get('config_image_additional_width'), $this->config->get('config_image_additional_height')),
      'popup' => $product_info['image'] ? $this->model_tool_image->resize($product_info['image'], $this->config->get('config_image_popup_width'), $this->config->get('config_image_popup_height')) : false,
      'href' => $this->url->link('product/product', 'product_id=' . $product_info['product_id']),
    );
```

And lastly, (for the sake of simplicity) the IMG tag on the template:

```
<img src="<?php echo $product['image2']; ?>" />
```

I've managed to whittle down errors until I'm left with an **UndefinedIndex: product_id** (and the main product image just duplicates on the page)... but now I'm totally stuck.

I'm dying to learn this... but I'm not even sure what the problem is... "product_id" is already used in this controller multiple times, I don't know why I would need to register it again... so I don't understand why it's Undefined.

Sorry for the long post, any insight would be appreciated... just trying to get Additional product images to display on a page other than "Product.tpl"

---

EDIT: Adding full page code for reference...
too long for Stack, used pastebin:

Wholesale.php (relevant code is easy to spot, widely spaced/commented):
http://pastebin.com/7HRdw3Sp

TemplateFile.tpl (trimmed for ease/redundancy):
http://pastebin.com/tdMB0kpe

Anyway, I appreciate any insight...
I've been trialling this a million different ways for the last 3 days, I can't even get close. :/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you should try in this way in "Wholesale.php" controller (from the "Product.php" controller):

$this->load->model('tool/image');

```
        if ($product_info['image']) {
            $this->data['popup'] = $this->model_tool_image->resize($product_info['image'], $this->config->get('config_image_popup_width'), $this->config->get('config_image_popup_height'));
        } else {
            $this->data['popup'] = '';
        }

        if ($product_info['image']) {
            $this->data['thumb'] = $this->model_tool_image->resize($product_info['image'], $this->config->get('config_image_thumb_width'), $this->config->get('config_image_thumb_height'));
        } else {
            $this->data['thumb'] = '';
        }

        $this->data['images'] = array();

        $results = $this->model_catalog_product->getProductImages($this->request->get['product_id']);

        foreach ($results as $result) {
            $this->data['images'][] = array(
                'popup' => $this->model_tool_image->resize($result['image'], $this->config->get('config_image_popup_width'), $this->config->get('config_image_popup_height')),
                'thumb' => $this->model_tool_image->resize($result['image'], $this->config->get('config_image_additional_width'), $this->config->get('config_image_additional_height'))
            );
        }
```

Forward to view

```
            $this->data['products'][] = array(
                    'product_id' => $result['product_id'],
                    'thumb'      => $image,
```

img tag on .tpl file "reference of default theme"

```
 <?php if ($thumb || $images) { ?>
    <div class="left">
      <?php if ($thumb) { ?>
      <div class="image"><a href="<?php echo $popup; ?>" title="<?php echo $heading_title; ?>" class="colorbox" rel="colorbox"><img src="<?php echo $thumb; ?>" title="<?php echo $heading_title; ?>" alt="<?php echo $heading_title; ?>" id="image" /></a></div>
      <?php } ?>
      <?php if ($images) { ?>
      <div class="image-additional">
        <?php foreach ($images as $image) { ?>
        <a href="<?php echo $image['popup']; ?>" title="<?php echo $heading_title; ?>" class="colorbox" rel="colorbox"><img src="<?php echo $image['thumb']; ?>" title="<?php echo $heading_title; ?>" alt="<?php echo $heading_title; ?>" /></a>
        <?php } ?>
      </div>
      <?php } ?>
    </div>
    <?php } ?>
```

Comment: Thanks for taking the time man... unfortunately, there's something odd about this Wholesale mod, it's written a little differently from standard OC controllers... I'm going to post the controller/template pages... but I understand if nobody wants to touch it. :)

Comment: post the mod let me see if i can help you post it in pastebin or any other website and share the link

Answer (score 0):

I see few errors in your controller

1. In your modification starting at line 124 you are using array `$product_info[]` which is defined  on line 427 (also that will change in each iteration ,so you must do all edits inside that foreach loop only )
2. In same modification you are using `$this->request->get['product_id']` which i am pretty sure is not defined. to verify it see if the url has something like `product_id=`, it would not be there, so you can't use it
3. modification around line 407 does not make much sense

I hope these points should be enough to get you started